# Why unable to start new activity when click on the rate design button

Tags: java, android

When I click on the rate design button it stops, I doubt is my manifest because I have check it already below are my codes. I have also enter the error log. Can someone help me instead of rating down for this question

Answer (score 5):

Your forget to add

```
 setContentView(R.layout.yourlayout);
```

before Button `initialization` in `onCreate(....)`

### Correct:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.yourLayout);

Button btnRating = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rd);

    btnRating.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NearablesDemoActivity.this, MainActivityRating.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @minseungjin what you added??

Comment: I have added setContentView before that

Comment: @minseungjin Plz go to [Check this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)

Comment: @minseungjin And you sure layout contains rd button

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

Comment: @minseungjin Ook fine. now post all logcat and before doing this add your activity in manifets.xml

Comment: @minseungjin error is not related to this question. so better to ask new question with new logcat and code.

Comment: Hi @MD, I have added the logcat and changed the question

Comment: I also would like to post a new question but I'm banned because of the keyboard warriors that is always rating the question down rather than helping

Comment: @minseungjin Your way is wrong for asking a questions. accept the answer and ask another question is better then you edit the current question. this is the of SO.